# How to encode data with multiple class labels?

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a classification problem with multiple classes, say A, B, C and D. My data has the following y labels:

```
y0 = [['A'], ['B'], ['A','D'], ['A'], ['A','C','D'], ['D'], ..., ['C'], ['A','B','C','D'] , ['B']]
```

I want to train a Random Forest classifier on these labels. First I need to encode the labels. I first tried `LabelEncoder`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit_transform(y0)
# encoded labels: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, ... 5, 6, 1], dtype=int64)
```

I also tried `OneHotEncoder`, but obviously, neither `LabelEncoder` nor `OneHotEncoder` would work here. The thing is that I cannot encode data with multiple class labels (e.g. `['A','B','C']`). I guess these trivial encoding methods are not the way to go here, so what is the best way to encode my class labels? To clarify, I don't want to treat e.g. `['A','B']` as a completely different class from `['A']` or `['B']`. I want it to be a different class but at the same time still inherit features from both A and B classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem is called *multilabel* (as opposed to *multiclass* where each sample has exactly one class label), and sklearn expects multilabel problems to have the target encoded as a binary array of shape `(n_samples, n_labels)`.  You can encode your data in that format using [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `OneHotEncoder` or `LabelEncoder` You can use `OrdinalEncoder` which encodes categorical features as an integer array.

Resulting classes will be on ordinal scale, so for example in alphabetical order `A`, `AB`, `AD` etc.

Question may be if `AB` is more similar to `AC` or to `AD`. I mean alphabetical order may not reflect real similarity, like in ordinal scale `'cold','warm','hot'`, so manual encoding and reordering should be used. But this details require some domain knowledge.